# AS3 -- Automatically saving and loading data

Tags: actionscript-3

I have one more question, then I'll be done for a while I hope.

My app is 100% complete, except for one problem. The app I use generally has people swapping screens very frequently, and every time they return to a specific screen the information is reset, just as if you're entering it for the first time.

I'm aware of Shared Objects, but don't have a clue on getting it to work properly. When I think I have it right, I'll go into the app, swap screens and everything will appear as if it was entered for the first time without any value changes, despite no compiler errors when I go to test it.

What I'm aiming to do is this - the moment you change the value of a string, it saves itself to the app as soon as it's changed. At the beginning of each screen it would call up the data that was saved to it. (There are reset buttons that change it to how it was if someone wanted to reset.)

Can anyone help with this? I really appreciate it!

Comment: The SharedObject class is so well documented and tutorialized online that it's hard to understand what you mean by "... don't have a clue..." How about reading up on it and then coming back here with a specific problem with a specific aspect of SharedObjects that's troubling you? Here's one place to start: http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3sharedobject/

Comment: Drop MovieClips altogether, and use Sprites, one per frame, as instances, so that when you `addChild()` the prevous frame sprite, its state remains the same as when you've last removed it.